# Вопрос по типографике

Tags: редактура

В книге в нескольких местах размещены иллюстрации: портреты Иванова и Петрова. Куда надо поместить информацию об авторских правах на портреты? Надо это сделать в виде следующего предложения:
Представленные в книге фотографии  портретов Иванова, Петрова взяты из частной коллекции. Авторы: Сидоров, Ковалев.

Comment: Вопрос имеет отношение к проблеме достижения информативности фразы. Вопрос общий, хотя автором почему-то притянут к типографике — искусству «оформления при помощи наборного (не рисованного) текста».

Comment: "притянут к типографике" - потому-что не знаю куда отнести. Буду благодарен за помощь в разрешении вопросов. К утру надо передать на окончательную вёрстку и потом в печать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Авторство произведений — дело за малым исключением индивидуальное. Обобщение одной фразой, иначе оно выглядит странно, должно быть хоть чем-то обосновано, как в части моделей, так и в отношении к авторам (если речь не идёт о соавторстве).

Портреты Иванова работы Петрова из собрания Сидорова представлены на стр. N, стр. NN.

Портрет Петрова работы Сидорова из коллекции Иванова представлен на вкладыше N.

Comment: Можно ли разместить это предложение (эти предложения) на 2-й странице, после аннотации или после авторских знаков?

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы вопрос посмотрела Galina Avanesova
(не знаю как ей направить).

Comment: Не видя макета, не зная жанра, объёма и пр., рекомендовать что-то? Пробежитесь по схожим книгам, журналам своей домашней библиотеки, — это подскажет.